# Git issues with VSCode - Why can't I compare my active branch to other branches or what is in Git Stash with VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions

OS: CENTOS
VSCODE: 1.69.2

Trying to get VSCode to do what I use to be able to do with IntelliJ.

A couple issues that I am having with this VSCode (Free crap version)

1. Compare current modified file to - Git Stash
2. Compare current modified file to - any other branch or history

First #1 : I cannot use the GitLens because it requires version 2.x of Git and I have 1.8.x and cannot get the update because the SAs said that we are not allowed due to security policies from updating at this time. I've been asking for months.

Second #1 : So using the Git tab and the Git Stash tab when I click on something that I have stashed my expectation is that the file is being compared to what is CURRENT on my file system. This is not the case as I verified this morning the left side of the display appears to be the last commit to the branch and the right is the file stashed. I need a comparison of what is current to the stash. I'm constantly having to use Meld to verify changes which is just a pain in the ass.

Third #2 : In the file explorer window I cannot right click and view folder history. Additionally right clicking on a file and compare it to anything at all. Nothing happens when I view file history, file diff etc.

Fourth #2 : I've done fresh clones and I've had the SAs reinstall the software still nothing.

Lastly this is another error I get within VSCode and have been googling and reading what I have found in Git website but no solution on how to resolve it. When trying to view Git information I get in the lower right corner of the IDE an error message of

> Changing the repository failed: ENOENT. no such file or directory,
> open '/mypath/--git-common-dir/packed-refs'

This issue has cost me more hours than I can remember. Today alone for trying to deal with 5 modified files and this post I've spent the last nearly 2 hours on. **So, I'm really desperate for some help here.**

I'd switch back but project is too cheap and they are paying exponentially in labor for this darn software forced on us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not had any luck finding a solution within this IDE.

What I have to do is have the following setup

1. Primary project folder location
2. Secondary project folder location

Then in my Secondary project folder location pull the branch I want to compare the Primary to.

Open up 'Meld' comparison tool.
Compare Primary to Secondary and select the files to move or files to compare in order to manage the Primary project.

***Found another way to run MELD***
register meld as your diff tool

```
git config --global diff.tool meld
```

Now, to compare your current branch to another branch in MELD do this

```
git difftool -d <branch name>
```

Meld will open up a comparison. In my case the left side is the branch I specified and the right side is my current branch I'm on.